# http only cookie not working on express js with reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, session-cookies, nginx-reverse-proxy

Good day people i have a node js appplication which i use nginx as reverse proxy.
whenever i set cookie it works but the httpOnly and secure flag is not ticked,
please i need solution this is an image of the problem[the cookie when set on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GnrK.jpg)

[my nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEr3G.png)

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:8080",
      "http://thegainer.xyz",
      "https://thegainer.xyz"
    ],
    exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"]
  })
); 



  res.cookie("token", JSON.stringify(accessToken), {
secure: true,
httpOnly: true,
maxAge: 2592000000
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh sorry i got my answer.

forgot to add `app.set("trust proxy",1)` on my frontend code this happened because I was not using nginx for static files but another nodejs server